# Was bedeutet "ins Blaue gehen"?

Tags: idiom

Aus dem Buch "Der Hobbit":

> "doch nicht der Gandalf, der es auf dem Gewissen hat,
>   daß so viele brave Burschen und Mädchen einfach ins
>   Blaue gingen, verrückte Abenteuer zu erleben."

Was bedeutet "ins Blaue gehen"? (Und sollte es in der neuen Rechtschreibung nicht "dass" sein?)

Comment: Wow, that's a weird sentence... which translation are you reading? O.o Anyway, for learners I'd recommend original German books for children, e.g. Erich Kästner, Michael Ende or Ottfried Fischer.

Comment: Wenn der Titel *Der Hobbit* (und nicht *der kleine Hobbit*) ist, handelt es sich vermutlich um Kreges Übersetzung (siehe [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Hobbit)). Zumandest nach dem, was ich von eingefleischten Tolkien-Fans aus meiner Bekanntschaft mitbekommen habe, sind die deutschen Übersetzungen nicht unumstritten.

Comment: @Raphael - it's a PDF version, but the title pages seem to be missing; the first page is immediately the story. So I don't know which translation it is. Anyway, since it seems to use the old "Rechtschreibung" I think I better find a more recent translation. (about Kästner, I already read "Drei Männer im Schnee")

Answer (score 4):

I know "ins Blaue" mostly from another context:

> Der Schuss ging ins Blaue.

Here, it means that the shot went anywhere but where it was supposed to be going ("in den Himmel", figuratively)

This has since been adapted to (metaphoric) use, e.g.

> Ich habe einfach ins Blaue hineingeraten.

meaning you just guessed randomly.

So, in this instance, the sentence means something like

> .. doch das war nicht der Gandalf, der dafür verantwortlich war, dass so viele brave junge Leute auf gut Glück in die Welt zogen, um verrückte Abenteuer zu erleben."

You may want to check the original text for verification (I don't have it handy).

Answer (score 2):

It's the same in English, really.

> "Not the Gandalf who was responsible for so many quiet lads and lasses going off into the Blue for mad adventures?"

I'm not even sure how idiomatic it is in German, but the meaning should be obvious. And, yes, *daß* is no longer correct nach *der neuen Rechtschreibung*.

Comment: O dear, now I have to go to the English site to ask about "going off into the blue", because I hadn't heard that before either. :-)

Comment: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=827168 :-)

Comment: It is idiomatic in German, especially as the destination of a journey (cf. original question). Second most frequent use is (IMHO) for shooting.